# Prove $O(2)$ is non-abelian?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

$$O(2) = \{Q\in \mathbb{F}^{2\times 2} | Q^TQ= QQ^T=I\}$$
What is the most elegant way to prove that $O(2)$ is non-Abelian?

Here is my thinking: I know that $O(2)$ can be generated by reflections and moreover two reflections result in a rotation. Rotations commute with each other, but reflections do not
$$
ROT(\theta/2)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It suffices to show that $$ROT(\phi/2)ROT(\theta/2)\neq ROT(\theta/2)ROT(\phi/2)$$ for some $\phi,\theta\in (0,2\pi)$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\phi & \sin\phi \\ \sin\phi & -\cos\phi
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\phi\cos\theta + \sin\phi\sin\theta
&
\cos\phi\sin\theta-\sin\phi\cos\theta
\\
\sin\phi\cos\theta-\cos\phi\sin\theta
&
\sin\phi\sin\theta+\cos\phi\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\phi & \sin\phi \\ \sin\phi & -\cos\phi
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\phi\cos\theta + \sin\phi\sin\theta
&
\sin\phi\cos\theta-\cos\phi\sin\theta
\\
\cos\phi\sin\theta-\sin\phi\cos\theta
&
\sin\phi\sin\theta+\cos\phi\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We see that indeed the two matrices do not commute since their top-right and bottom-left elements switch signs.

---

**My question: Is there a purely algebraic proof that does not need geometric consideration? If not, what is the most common proof of this result?**

Comment: All you need to show is that $gh \ne hg$ for a *single* pair $g,h \in O(2).$ Try some simple ones!

Comment: Didn't you just say it yourself. You can expand $O(2) = Rot(\phi)+Ref(\theta)$ which you can now apply with the knowledge of how they work. Or do you want to see a proof why rotation don't commute?

Comment: @MichaelParis I was wondering if there was a proof that followed simpily from the fact that $Q^TQ=QQ^T=I$ without any geometric considerations.

Comment: In some sense there cannot be a purely algebraic proof that works over any field, because if $\mathbb{F}$ is the field with two elements then $O(2)$ is the cyclic group with two element.

Comment: One contradiction will do, there are obviously instances where commutativity will hold ($\phi=\theta-\pi n$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$) but if you show one contradiction, the group isn't Albelian. (You can just pick a  $\phi$ & $\theta$ that don't satisfy the above.)

Comment: In fact $O(2)$ is abelian whenever $\mathbb{F}$ has characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 4):

Take for example

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\!-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\!-1&0\end{pmatrix}\neq\begin{pmatrix}0&\!-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\!-1\end{pmatrix}$$

...over any field with characteristic$\,\neq2\;$

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks. Your comment came while I was adding the info.